# My program only works when I declare an extra array

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, unix, gcc

I'm building a simple shell for a class. There are two programs in my shell directory, called "alomundo" and "echo". "./alomundo" prints "Alo mundo!" to console, and ./echo  executes the ubuntu echo with given args.
The thing is my program only works if I declare the char aux[15]. Notice I don't use it aux for nothing. Can anyone understand whats wrong?

An example input would be

> ./shell echo a b, alomundo, echo abc

The correct output is

> a b
>
> Alo mundo!
>
> abc

The output when char aux[15] is not declared is just:

> Alo mundo!
>
> abc

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char aux[15]; // <---- GRRRR
    int child; // will hold the childs PID after fork()
    int i = 0; // counter to loop through this mains *argv[]
    int t = 0; // auxiliar counter to loops
    int arg_len; // will hold the length of each argument while the argument is being processed
    int args = 0; // current number of arguments in the argv1 vector
    int send = 0; // boolean to check if the command should be executed in the current loop or not
    char *command; // string to hold the main command name

    char *argv1[15]; // vector to hold the arguments passed to execve

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        arg_len = strlen(argv[i]);
        argv1[args] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        for(t=0; t<25; t++) {
            argv1[args][t] = '\0';
        }

        if (argv[i][arg_len-1] == ',') {
            argv[i][arg_len-1] = '\0';
            send = 1;
        }
        else if (i == (argc-1)) {
            send = 1;
        }

        if (args == 0) {
            command = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
            strcpy(command, "./");
            strcpy(argv1[args], "./");
            strcat(command, argv[i]);
        }
        strcat(argv1[args], argv[i]);
        args++;

        if (send) {
            child = fork();
            if (child == 0) {
                argv1[args+1] = 0;
                execve(command, &argv1[0], envp);
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                waitpid(child);
                free(command);
                for (t=0; t<args; t++) {
                    free(argv1[t]);
                    argv1[t] = NULL;
                }
                args = 0;
                send = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, you’re stepping outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: this is definitely a result of memory corruption. You need carefully check your lengths of arguments against the constants you used,  like `15`. Alternatively you can run valgrind. But the best would be rewrite your program to use size checking and sized string manipulations, like `strncpy`.

Comment: The code doesn't compile with gcc, as `envp` is not declared and `waitpid()` wants `#include <sys/wait.h>`, so it's not clear that debugging what you've shown us will solve the actual problem.

Comment: I compiled it with gcc, strange. I will get back to you guys as soon as I find out what it was. Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `waitpid(child)` seems wrong. Try:

```
// ...
#include <sys/wait.h>
// ...
    pid_t child;
    int wstatus;
// ...
            else {
                wait(&wstatus);
```

2. `envp` is not declared. Try:

```
// ...
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
// ...
```

3. Off-by-one error in `argv1` processing. Try:

```
// ...
            if (child == 0) {
                argv1[args] = 0;
                execve(command, argv1, envp); // why use &argv1[0] ?
// ...
```

I think (3) is the culprit.

Compiling with different levels of optimisation (`-O`, etc) seems to affect whether or not the erroneous `+1` causes a problem.

Comment: Do you mean "char  *envp[]" instead of  "*envp[]" only?

Comment: I will test it soon and get back to you with an answer!